# How to open Android camera in Food Mode programmatically?

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-galaxy

I'm trying to make an app that triggers the native camera intent. I already have this line in my code

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

I am wondering if there are any extras I can add before starting this intent to launch the native camera in Food Mode. I am using a Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no single "native camera" for Android. There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. There are hundreds of pre-installed ("native") camera apps on those models.

Second, your `Intent` does not necessarily involve the "native camera". Users can install other camera apps, and those camera apps can offer an activity that supports that `Intent` structure.

Third, other than `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, [there are no documented configuration options for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

So, there is no standard way of asking for this mode, or any other mode.

I don't know what "food mode" is exactly, but if is some feature of some app from Samsung on some device, you would have to contact Samsung to see if they have some specific API for interacting with that app and asking for "food mode".

<sub>and now I'm hungry...</sub>

Comment: So it's not possible to allow the user to switch the mode, for example, between panorama, slow motion or pro? Unless the selected camera app supports switching the mode?

Comment: @ClassA: Whether the user can or cannot switch to those modes is to the developers of the camera app.